# FOP not generating readable PDF

Tags: xslt, glassfish, apache-fop

My enviroment is :

Glassfish 3.12
FOP-1.0
 and I am trying to generate a PDF using FOP via a servlet.

The XML file is :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
    <LIST>
        <user>
            <FIRSTNAME>Hi</FIRSTNAME>
            <LASTNAME>Hello</LASTNAME>
            <EMAIL>a@a.com</EMAIL>
</user>
        <user>
            <FIRSTNAME>aa</FIRSTNAME>
            <LASTNAME>ddd</LASTNAME>
            <EMAIL>a@kk.com</EMAIL>
</user>
</LIST>
```

the XSL is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="LIST">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page">
                    <fo:region-body margin="1in"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>

            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font="12pt Times">

                    <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
                        <fo:table-body>
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
               text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        First Name.
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
               text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        Last Name.
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
               text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        Email
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                            <xsl:for-each select="./user">
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                                        <fo:block>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                                        <fo:block>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="FIRSTNAME" />
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                                        <fo:block>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="LASTNAME" />
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="EMAIL" />
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>

                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
            </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the servlet code is :

```
try
{
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();

            TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent(); 
            //Setup FOP
            Fop fop =
                    fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF,foUserAgent, bout);
            //Setup Transformer
            Source xsltSrc = new StreamSource(new File("test.xsl"));
            Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xsltSrc);
            //Make sure the XSL transformation's result is piped through to FOP
            Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
            //Setup input
            Source src = new StreamSource(new File("xmlfile2.xml"));
            //Start the transformation and rendering process

            transformer.transform(src, res);
            //Prepare response

            response.setContentLength(bout.size());

            //Send content to Browser

             response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                    "attachment;filename=pdffile.pdf");
            response.getOutputStream().write(bout.toByteArray());
            response.getOutputStream().flush();



        } 

        catch(TransformerConfigurationException tce)
        {
                tce.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(FOPException fope)
        {
                 fope.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(TransformerException te)
        {
                 te.printStackTrace();

         }
```

The PDF is generated / downloaded , but whI try to open it, it says :

```
Adobe Reader could not open the file 'pdffile.pdf' because it is etiher not a supported file or because the file has been  damaged.
```

Any idea where am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moved response.setContentType("application/pdf"); just above these lines :

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                    "attachment;filename=pdffile.pdf");
            response.getOutputStream().write(bout.toByteArray());
            response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

And the code is working fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed the OutputStream:

```
response.getOutputStream().close();
```